# Sanitizing HTML code

Tags: html

I have a webpage that reads data from a database and then displays it, but I've just found an issue with data that could contain HTML in it.

In my database I have the following 3 entries:

Bob

Jill

```
<button onClick="alert('hi')">Click me!</button>
```

Now I have my HTML page that gets the data and displays it and has a click event on each entry, so an example would be:

```
<div onClick="DoSomething()">
   <a>Bob</a>
</div>
```

My code is removing escape characters so < becomes `&lt;`

That works fine until I get to the last entry and I end up with:

```
<div onClick="DoSomething()">
   <a>&lt;button onClick="alert('hi')"&gt;Click me too!&lt;/button&gt;</a>
</div>
```

It displays as expected so I would see:

```
<button onClick="alert('hi')">Click me too!</button>
```

but it also is picking up that there should be a click event trying to show "hi".

Does anyone know how I can safely stop the onClick that is being defined by the name but still have my onClick event on the surrounding div.

I can't restrict the names that can be added to the database.

Comment: you might open your app to XSS attacks if you allow such things not to be sanitized. somebody could theoretically inject code and run it

Comment: The bad name that contains the html does not currently exist, but could.  This is showing an extreme example but I have no way of restricting the names that could be entered onto the database (this is a legacy desktop app, 15+ years old - that now has a web interface).  So yes I do need to sanitize but I don't know how I can do that but still retain the name the user entered.  I thought by changing the escape characters this would do it.

Comment: @sbarnby71 If you're using PHP, you can use striptags: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php. For other languages, the logic is the same.

Comment: I can't just strip the tags from the text as I need to maintain the name of item, so if the user called <<bob>> then that's what they called it, I can't just return it as bob.

Comment: But a real user without bad intentions will not put his name between tags.

Comment: Sorry I can't agree with that, a user could quite innocently enter a name that they have no idea is a html tag, like I said even using a < or > is picked up up by most strip tag bits of code, so Jill > Bob should be a valid name, but the > would be stripped out.  Not the desired result I need.

Answer (score 0):

Figured what was happening.  When I create the html elements that hold the item names I was creating a custom attribute on it called DispName and putting the name of the item in it, eg:

```
<div onclick="DoSomething()" DispName="&lt;button onClick="alert('hi')"&gt;Click me too!&lt;/button&gt;">
    <div>&lt;button onClick="alert('hi')"&gt;Click me too!&lt;/button&gt;</div>
<div>
```

So when my onclick event was called I would use .getAttribute("DispName") on the entity that was clicked and assumed that I would get the value **<button onClick="alert('hi')">Click me too!</button>** back but what I was getting back was the unsanitized text of `<button onClick="alert('hi')">Click me too!</button>`.

I think what is happening is as soon as I add my html elements to the DOM, the attribute DispName's value is unsanitized by the DOM.  The sanitized script that is not in an attribute is left as I expected.

Not sure if anyone can confirm this, but now I know why I then get the rogue script running when I try and use the value in DispName.